# Program Question

Tags: search

In the search feature, where is the date range filter? We recently transitioned to JManage, which uses your programming for their database. Their documentation specifies that one can filter the search through a date range but, after extensive research on our part through our own use of the program, we cannot find where this option lies. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can you explain more about jmanage? what version of civicrm are they providing you?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I was curious too - https://www.jvillagenetwork.com/services/relationship-management

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM does provide date range search on Report Filter and Search form. Below are few examples

[image] 
[image]